# Rows to columns in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table as below

```
Customer    Product Price

C1          P1      123

C1          P2      124

C2          P1      123

C2          P2      124
```

I need to display the above output as below in DB2 query

```
Customer    P1  P2

C1          123 124

C2          123 124
```

Please help me in achieving the above output in DB2.

Comment: This is known as a [tag:pivot] operation.  What version, please?  Recent versions support the `PIVOT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate using a `case` statement

```
select 
Customer
max(case when product='P1' then Price END) P1,
max(case when product='P2' then Price END) P2
From
table
group by customer
```